# How to determine air flow required?

Tags: air, convection

I am making a sound dampening box for a vacuum pump. It’s loud almost 96dB. I have an ultra quiet fan to vent heat out of the box. I want to calculate how to make a couple small inlet holes while still giving the fan the ability to pull maximum air if needed. How do I find how many holes I need and how big those holes need to be. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use holes alone - they will let the sound radiate outside regardless of size. Better to use baffles, so the sound needs to go through several reflections, and those should absorb as much of the sound as possible (for example, cover them with [acoustic pyramid foam](https://www.thefoamfactory.com/acousticfoam/pyramidfoam.html)).

It should be obvious that when the sound has to go through several reversals of direction, the same must happen to the airflow. So size your fan such that it can pull enough air through the system of baffles while not exceeding the limit temperature of the pump.

For best efficiency, the total area of holes should be larger than the cross section of the fan to allow for low airspeed. This will again go counter to maximum cooling, but will produce the best cooling effect for a given fan power consumption.

To hope for maximum flow goes against your target of soundproofing. Make up your mind what you prefer.